# SQL Unique Constraint allows violation with nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, localdb

I have a table that has a Non-clustered, Unique index on 3 columns, "MenuId", "Name", and "ParentId".

The problem is, I am able to insert multiple rows into this table that violate the unique constraint - when ParentId is set to NULL as you can see below.

If I try to add duplicate rows and ParentId is not null, the unique constraint works as expected.

My understanding of unique indexes is that it would only allow a single unique combination of the columns participating in the index, so I would expect in the image below to have been able to instert the first row but it should have thrown an exception for violating the index when inserting the second (and third) row - but it doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?

I am using SQL LocalDb.

[image: Table in LocalDb]

Update:  I am using EF Core to generate the database from code and it seems that in this case, the Unique Constraint is being created with a WHERE clause to ignore when ParentId or Name is NULL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MenuItem_MenuId_ParentId_Name]
    ON [dbo].[MenuItem]([MenuId] ASC, [ParentId] ASC, [Name] ASC) 
WHERE ([ParentId] IS NOT NULL AND [Name] IS NOT NULL);
```

Embaressingly, when I was exploring the Unique constraint in SQL Server Explorer properties window, this WHERE clause wasn't apparant - I simply checked the Unique constraint existed, and that the columns I expected where included - however that wasn't enough. Thank you to the commentor below who couldn't reproduce and made me actually inspect the script for the index where this WHERE clause became apparant. I have now moved my question to one relating to why EF produces this in my case:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17586

Comment: Some databases allow duplicates for `NULL` values in a unique index; some do not.  It depends on the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see. In which case, if anyone could include in an answer how to achieve the desired constraint in the case of sql localdb that would be very beneficial, thanks

Comment: I tried both enterprise(2012) and express(2014) version. `NULL` will trigger if duplicated validation in both cases. Are you sure you set unique index correctly?

Comment: I'll update my answer with the full SQL to create the tables involved, the relationships and constraints. As far as I can tell, I haven't made any mistake with the unique index.

Comment: @蕭為元  so it looks like the problem might be this.. I am using EF Core to generate the database from c# code. The unique constraint generated looks like this: 
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MenuItem_MenuId_ParentId_Name]
    ON [dbo].[MenuItem]([MenuId] ASC, [ParentId] ASC, [Name] ASC) WHERE ([ParentId] IS NOT NULL AND [Name] IS NOT NULL);

I was not aware unique constraints could have a WHERE clause, but it looks like that is potentially the problem.. I'll raise a question with the EF guys to see why thats being generated like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @蕭為元 for prompting me to look at the Unique constraint in more detail, and not just in the properties window!

The UNIQUE index has a WHERE clause that was causing it to ignore records that has NULL values for Parent ID or Name:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MenuItem_MenuId_ParentId_Name]
    ON [dbo].[MenuItem]([MenuId] ASC, [ParentId] ASC, [Name] ASC) 
WHERE ([ParentId] IS NOT NULL AND [Name] IS NOT NULL);
```

This was generated by EF - and that's the type of problem you hit when relying on ORM's to do stuff for you and assume they do what you want - *slap myself on wrist*

Answer (score 0):

Set -1 as the default value to `ParentId`.
Or

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT cUniq UNIQUE (MenuId,Name,ParentId);
```

Comment: Good idea but I can not. Parent ID is a foreign key to same table I'd column. It's a hierarchy. So I'd have to insert a dummy record with a -1 I'd to allow.